# error MSB6006: "midl.exe" exited with code -2147024774

Tags: windows-10, c++, visual-studio-2015

I am having a project with uses ATL in windows.I am trying to build it in Visual Studio 2015, x64 platform, production mode but I am running into error. How to fix this?

Comment: debug it first then send in the code causes error here. or more detailed error message or log file if anything get created

Comment: I tried building it in "debug"mode then it showed "mc.exe related  error". On suggestion of a friend, i installed VS2015 update 3 package. Now the project builds fine. Thanks for you suggestion too :)